# Selecting Specified Results Without the Contain Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a query that will provide me all instances that have an '(AB)' in the field_name column:

```
select distinct field_name, count(distinct field_id) as field_amounts
from data.table
where field_name like '%(AB)%'
group by field_name
order by field_amounts desc;
```

This would produce a result like:

| field_name | field_amounts |
| --- | --- |
| A (AB) | 10 |
| B (AB) | 7 |

Now, I am looking to grab all the instances in the data set with the same exact field_names from this result but without the '(AB)' within the name. So, something like this:

| field_name | field_amounts |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| B | 17 |

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
To clarify, there are instances in the data that have '(AB)' and ones that don't. I want all the field names with '(AB)' but then also the ones that have the same field_names but without the '(AB)'. For example, if the entire data set looks like this:

| field_name | field_id |
| --- | --- |
| A (AB) | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B (AB) | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 5 |
| D (AB) | 6 |
| D | 7 |

Then I would not want the field_name 'C' as there aren't any instances of 'C (AB)'. So, the new query I want would grab A, B, and D and count the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the REPLACE function

Comment: Hello, I am not trying to replace values within the data set...

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the query by editing 3rd line to:

```sql
where field_name not like '%(AB)%'
```

Comment: This would provide results that are unneeded. There are instances of 'A (AB)' and 'A' but also instances of 'C' but no instances of 'C (AB)', for example.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE  field_name ='A' OR field_name ='B';

Comment: If there are 50+ instances, it does not make sense to use OR and type out all of them. I know I could do that, but would not make sense with larger data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(t.field_name, '(AB)', '')) field_name,
       COUNT(*) field_amounts
FROM tablename t
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(t.field_name LIKE '%(AB)%') > 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f02956def39560d00f499d97fb55df3d).

Comment: How would this query change if I wanted only the instances of 'A', 'B', 'D' occurring instead of both 'A (AB)' and 'A'? The reason is because I want to compare the two amounts (the instances of 'A' vs instances of 'A (AB)')